# Undefined Index PHP en el header de mi pagina

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, php7

estoy trabajando en el proyecto web de mi trabajo, estaba realizando un nuevo formulario a la cual estaba tratando de asignarle en el menú de mi header para que se pueda acceder a través del cursor, me figura este error en el log del apache

> [Wed Feb 26 13:19:37.911964 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 2832:tid 1836] [client ::1:52386] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: adjudicacionLlamado in C:\xampp\htdocs\siciap_01\vistas\header.php on line 226, referer: http://localhost/siciap_01/vistas/escritorio.php

El codigo que tengo en el header en esa linea 226 es esto

```
            if ($_SESSION['adjudicacion']==1)
        {
                   echo '<li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-book fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <span>Ajudicación</span>
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="treeview-menu"> ';

                        if ($_SESSION['adjudicacionEjecucion']==1)
                       { 
                        echo '<li><a href="adjudicacionEjecucion.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Porcentaje de Ejecucion</a></li>';
                       } 
                       if ($_SESSION['adjudicacionLlamado']==1)
                      { 
                         echo '<li><a href="adjudicacionLlamado.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Llamado</a></li>';
                      } 
                       if ($_SESSION['adjudicacionProveedorAtraso']==1)
                       { 
                            echo '<li><a href="proveedorAtraso.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Provedores con Atrasos</a></li>';
                       } 
                        if ($_SESSION['adjudicacionProducto']==1)
                       { 
                            echo '<li><a href="adjudicacionProducto.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Productos</a></li>';
                       } 
                        echo '</ul>
                        </li>';
```

Por otra parte si a este fragmento del codigo

```
if ($_SESSION['adjudicacionEjecucion']==1)
```

lo dejo como está y hago la referencia a mi formulario adjudicacionLLamado.php lo ejecuta sin problema y funciona correctamente, pero no como mencione al tratar incorporar el 5to boton a mi menu me aparece error.
Lo siento si redacté bien mi problema, estoy empezando a trabajar como desarrolador web y no poseo mucha experiencia

Comment: Lo que nos muestras no es un **error** es un **notice**. En PHP no ocasionan la interrupción de la ejecución. Lo que dice el **notice** es que estás tratando de acceder al índice *adjudicacionLlamado* dentro de `$_SESSION` y que no lo está encontrando. Revisa a ver si estás guardado bien esa variable de sesión en tu código porque de no encontrarla no se va a meter por `if ($_SESSION['adjudicacionLlamado']==1)` imposibilitando que se pinte el enlace a la sección dentro de tu menú.

Comment: que te devuelve un ``var_dump($_SESSION)`` ?